# Redirecting URLs with Multiple Parameters via HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

How would I do this 301 redirect in my htaccess file?

**OLD URLs**

http://www.domain.com/newsletter/modules.php?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=221

http://www.domain.com/newsletter/modules.php?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=224

**NEW URLs**

For 221 - https://www.domain.com/news/

For 224 - https://www.domain.com/treatments/laser-comb/iso-certification/

Explanation:  Basically everything is the same in the OLD urls except for the article ID number at the end.

Comment: I'm not a developer.  Just a lay person who has found numerous helpful replies for similar redirect questions.  Currently have no attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your htaccess file, add the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /newsletter/modules\.php\?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=221 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/news/? [L,R=301]
#2)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /newsletter/modules\.php\?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=224 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/treatments/laser-comb/iso-certification/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: what is `THE_REQUEST` ?

Comment: It's a predefined server variable.

Please read the mod-rewrite documentation : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Ok-  I see it.   Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance.  I apologize for what may be a dumb question, but I am not a tech person.  Just the website owner.  We have constructed an htaccess file that is about 3,500 lines long now.  Its a 17 year old website with multiple redesigns/migrations.  I have all the "RewriteRules", "RedirectMatch", and "RewriteConds" in the top half of the file.  The WordPress stuff in the middle.  And the standard "Redirect 301"s in the bottom half.  Do you see any risk of adding these to the top half, causing things below them to stop working, or change function at all?