# Redirecting Forum Archive pages to the Forum home page/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Bear with me as I am not a developer and my "redirect guy" has been unreachable.  Here's the situation.  Our forums have a series of pages with URLs formatted like so:

http://www.domain.com/interact/archive/index.php/t-20810.html
http://www.domain.com/interact/archive/index.php/t-56307.html

So the URL is exactly the same, with the exception of the last part, which is always t(dash)anynumbers(.html)

The goal:  Redirect these URL's via 301 to:

https://www.domain.com/interact/

Note:  We already have an HTTP > HTTPS redirect in the htaccess so that's handled.

I see three attempts by my redirect guy to accomplish this.  Its possible one of them is *CORRECT*.

We later decided to 410 these URLS.

I am now required to put the 301 redirect back, but I don't know which (if any) of these are correctly done.

**Attempt 1:**

RewriteRule archive/index.php/t-([0-9]+).html$ http://www.domain.com/interact/threads/$1/ [R=301,L]

**Attempt 2:**

RewriteRule archive/index.php/f-([0-9]+).html$ http://www.domain.com/interact/forum/$1/ [R=301,L]

**Attempt 3:**

RewriteRule ^archive/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/interact/ [R=301,NC,L]

Which, if any of these, is the correct one?  If none, what is the correct method to 301 redirect:

http://www.domain.com/interact/archive/index.php/t-56307.html

to

https://www.domain.com/interact/

when

index.php/t-[ANYNUMBERS.html]

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting URLs with Multiple Parameters via HTACCESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428830/redirecting-urls-with-multiple-parameters-via-htaccess)

Comment: I think you need to hire a new redirect guy.